# Not getting a desired output in JAVA as expected

Tags: java

I have a JAVA code which prints a pattern. But I am not getting the output which I am looking for.

**Filename -> test.java**

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++);
            {
                System.out.print("1 ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It should print this

```
1
1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

But it is printing this as output

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Please rectify if there are any errors

Comment: Remove the semicolon after your inner for-loop.

Comment: Nope.  On Eclipse it prints the same.  The dangling semicolon is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added `;` in the second loop. That is why printing like this. Your eclipse code must be no `;` there. :)

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++);
            {
                System.out.print("1 ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a `;` after `for(j=0; j<=i; j++)`. Eclipse must be assuming you don't intend it to be there while other IDEs are not. Delete the `;` and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removed `;` after the second `for` loop.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("i ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```